# How to get iBeacon mac address?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want my application scan for iBeacon and show its mac address via Toast.

I have tried implement this tutorial to make it scan only but not works http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-programmatically-scan-or-discover-android-bluetooth-device/

(This tutorial including Scan/Pair but I need only to scan and get address.)

Comment: If the iBeacon is coming from an iPhone then you won't be able to see the MAC address.

Comment: I used Beacon Scanner application and it can detect my beacon. (I beacon is a small bluetooth device and it's not transmitting from iPhone)